# Is it possible to print the keys and associated values of a map on separate lines in Java?

Tags: java, maps

I am wondering is it possible to print the keys and associated values of a map on separate lines. I am new to Java and to maps. When I try printing using the normal `println` as on the last line it prints out the keys and value's inside a curly brace and all on 1 line. I know this is probably a silly question but I have been struggling with it for a while now and have not found a solution online or in any of my lecture notes. This is just a class I set up to try get it working before I try implement it on a bigger scale. Sorry in advance if my code or anything else does not appear in a conventional way, this is my first time to post.

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
public class tester {   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TreeMap<String, String> dir = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        String key = "b";
        String value = "2";
        String key1 = "a";
        String value2 = "1";
        dir.put(key, value);
        dir.put(key1, value2);
        System.out.println(dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: The default `TreeMap.toString` is what it is; it's really for "human display". To pretty-print it must be done using other means (e.g. manually or with a existing library).

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you have to loop through the map and print the keys and values on separate lines.

```
TreeMap<String, String> dir = new TreeMap<String, String>();

for(Entry<String, String> en: dir.entrySet()) {

    System.out.println(en.getKey());
    System.out.println(en.getValue());
}
```

Comment: -1 If you're just going to paste code, make sure to fix the typos.

Comment: @PaulBellora what is the typo now ??

Comment: @PaulBellora haha, i dint copy paste the code my friend, if i would have copy pasted it why would the typos appear??

Comment: Should the code be for(Map.Entry<String, String> en: dir.entrySet()) ?

Comment: @NiallByrne - Yeah, or you can import `java.util.Map.Entry`.

Comment: @NiallByrne you can use either, Map.Entry is a nested static interface with Map check out here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

Comment: @NiallByrne you are welcome :)dont forget to accept the most appropriate answer if yu are happy with one :)

Comment: @chaitanya10 I'm not sure how to accept the most appropriate answer. I have only being programming for 6 weeeks or so so I dont have a great understanding yet. With your for loop is there a particular name for that type of for loop ? I havn't used 1 like that before and i want to try understand it more, i have only ever used the for(int i =0; i<10; i++) type of for loops before.

Comment: @NiallByrne its called enhanced for loop or for each loop look at it here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes...

```
for (String key : dir.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + " = " + dir.get(key));
}
```

Have a look through the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) API for more info

**UPDATED with feeback back from Mik378**

As suggested by Mik378, to gain better performance you are better of using `Map.entrySet` ([Accessing the Map values using keySet iterator](http://javaantipatterns.wordpress.com/2007/11/22/accessing-the-map-values-using-keyset-iterator/))

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dir.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Why iterating through `keySet()` to process a `dir.get()` after => decrease performance. Look at this: http://javaantipatterns.wordpress.com/2007/11/22/accessing-the-map-values-using-keyset-iterator/

Comment: @Mik378 cause that's how I know how to do it ;) - Nice to learn something new, thanks...

Comment: Bigger is the amount of collisions within the map, bigger might be the decrease of performance due to the `get` process on each element.

Comment: @Mik378 There's no question. The second method is more efficient, no argument, but is related to the size of the map in question.  But regardless, one should practice good behavior and the `entrySet` is good behavior

Comment: I think the size of the map is a very little potential cause of the decrease of performance. Indeed, in an ideal scenario where there is no hash collision at all, the `TreeMap.get()` method is always O(1) ;) Anyway, the fact is: `keySet()` => let's throw it away :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the last line by:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dir.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(entry);
}
```

Will output:

```
a=1
b=2
```

Indeed, the `Entry`'s `toString()` method is already as:

```
public String toString() {
   return key + "=" + value;
}
```

Comment: `Map.Entry` is an interface, it's not a good idea to rely on the `toString` method, as not all implementations may support it - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're right :) But for a very small program as he did, there's no big danger. For sure, it would be effortless to redefine it as a kind of private method or utility Class's method.

Answer (score 0):

With lambda expressions it's simply:

```
propertiesMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.printf("%s=%s%n", key, value));
```